# Is there a way to send binary data to a C program from within GDB?

Tags: c, security, debugging, gdb

I am debugging a C program inside of GDB on linux. The C program prompts the user and then calls `read(0,&user_buffer,24)` where `user_buffer` is a 24-byte char buffer on the stack. I know that I can send binary data to the program from outside of gdb by e.g. `echo -e "\x41\x42\x43\x44" | <executable>`, but is it possible for me to directly write raw bytes to the prompt from within gdb? I've only ever seen this done externally as shown, or using python like `python -c 'print("\x00\xFF\xAB")'`  When I try to type in something like `\x41\x42\x43\x44` to the prompt within GDB, it interprets them as ascii chars. This is important for my security testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your desired input in a file, you can [redirect standard input with the `run` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Input_002fOutput.html#Input_002fOutput) to use that file.

```bash
$ echo -e "\x41\x42\x43\x44" > input.data
$ gdb a.out
# Set breakpoints etc.
(gdb) run < input.data
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible for me to directly write raw bytes to the prompt from within gdb?

I don't think so.

What you *can* do is set a breakpoint on the line immediately after `read`, hit `A` 24 times to make the `read` return, and then "stuff" the bytes you want into the buffer from GDB. Given `char buf[24] = "";`

```
(gdb) p buf
$1 = "", '\000' <repeats 23 times>

(gdb) set buf = "\x41\x42\x43\x44"
(gdb) p buf
$2 = "ABCD", '\000' <repeats 19 times>
```

This is also possible without access to source / debug info, but you'll have to cast the pointer that is the 2nd argument to `read` to `char[24]`.